# What is the URL for CAS_SERVER_URL?

Tags: python, django, cas

How do I know what is the url of my **CAS** (Central Authentication Service) source?

I installed django-cas into the folder `/home/myuser/webapps/djangoapp/lib/python2.7/django_cas`

I followed [this guide](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview) but I don't know what is the `CAS_SERVER_URL`. How do I know?

Thanks!

Comment: You would probably ask the people responsible for your local CAS instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django_CAS is just a client for authenticating against a [CAS server](http://www.jasig.org/cas).  The CAS_SERVER_URL is located where ever you have your instance of the CAS server running.

As a side note, if you are not the administrator of the CAS server, the CAS administrator will have to add the application to the approved services list in CAS.